# I can't see apache, nginx process while using "top" command

Tags: command-line, centos-6, linux-kvm

As the title said: "I can't see apache or nginx process while I'm using top command"
I'm using CentOS 6.5 and of course I already installed it on my server.

I run them as a service by using these commands:
`service nginx start` & `service httpd start`

[screenshot - click me!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wFvpH.jpg)

Could you help me know why I can't see it via `top` command?

Thanks.

Comment: As a starter: If you haven't configured nginx and apache to use different ports, you won't be able to run both of them in parallel.

Comment: Try the following and see if any return results: `pgrep apache` `pgrep httpd` `pgrep nginx`. Also in top, have you tried scrolling down? (use arrow keys). Finally, are they actually running? I.e. can you see see web pages when you connect to your server with a browser?

Comment: My web server run normally, I configure everything and it's working right now.
@flungo: pgrep nginx return 1988 & 1989

Comment: `top` is not suitable for listing processes. Use something like `ps aux`.

Comment: @DanielB: Thanks, you are genius! I don't know why `top` can't work in server, in my home PC & old server, `top` can show me everything I need.

Comment: Because `top` output is always sorted. It only shows top processes. Like most CPU usage, most memory usage etc. This is unrelated to desktop/server/embedded/whatever.

Answer (score 0):

Since `pgrep nginx` returns 1988 and your top seems to be sorted by CPU usage and then PID, I would suggest scrolling down till you get to the line that has PID 1988. You should be able to do this with the 'Page Down' Key or the down arrow key.

I am not exactly sure why you want to see it in top? If it is to see the CPU usage then if its not at the top of top with your current config, you can be sure its less than 0.05%. If it is to see memory usage then scroll till you find the PID for apache/nginx. And if you just want the PID, the `pgrep` command should have you covered.

IF you are not interested in monitoring any of these factors in realtime then `ps` is what you want and this can be helped with a command such as `ps aux | grep nginx`

As an alternative to top I would suggest `htop` which is colourful, and more feature packed including things like search and tree view. If I am also not mistaken top will not show every process in a process tree (for subprocesses) but that is visible in htop.